# How to hide horizontal scroll in table (ngGrid)?

Tags: css, angularjs, scrollbar, ng-grid

I'm using ngGrid for table but I don't know how I can remove horizontal scroll? Just "overflow-x: hidden"  unsuccessful

My table:

```
.row(ng-controller="MyCtrl")
.form.form-group
   .col-sm-8
       div.gridStyle(
        id="myTable"
        ng-grid="myTableGrid"
        )
   .col-sm-2
   .col-sm-2
```

Angular code:

```
    $scope.myTableGrid = {
      data: 'data',
      multiSelect: true,
      showSelectionCheckbox: true,
      columnDefs:[

        {field: 'program_name', displayName: 'Program name'},
        {field: 'date', displayName: 'Date'}

      ],


  }
```

And test data for table:

```
 $scope.data=  [
                {id:10, program_name:'program1', date: '13.02.2015 8:52:45'} ,
                {id:102, program_name:'program2', date: '13.02.2015 9:16:23'} ,
                {id:130, program_name:'program3', date: '13.02.2015 9:20:40'} ,
                {id:102, program_name:'program4', date: '13.02.2015 9:16:23'} ]
```

Comment: Is the answer below any use to you?

Comment: No,it does not work(

Comment: It's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vpee6rsd/4/ BUT there are no horizontal scroll =((( what ....

Comment: Since it's not recommended one. But its a small work around to solve the issue. Apply the `overflow-x` in your `index.html` or `index.cshtml` page's `html` tag like, `<html data-ng-app="app" style="overflow-x: hidden;">`. This will hide the horizontal scrollbar all over the application. In case if any of your page need the horizontal scrollbar, you need to explicitly write the code for the page.